# any way to retrieve a circular reference value

Tags: perl, memory-leaks, reference

I wrote th following program to see feature called circular reference in perl.

```
my $foo = 100;  
$foo = \$foo;
print "Value of foo is : ", $$foo, " " , $foo;
```

the output was:

```
Value of foo is : REF(0x21b632c) REF(0x21b632c)
```

but i was wondering where the value 100 gone can any one help me.or is it a memory leak?

Comment: The value of 100 was clobbered.  That is no different than saying, `$f = 100`, and then saying `$f = 'foobar'`.  The old value is lost.

Comment: Also, as perl uses a reference-counted garbage collector (plus a mark-and-sweep for circular references), there is no memory leak either.

Comment: @Phylogenesis It's new for me that Perl does mark-and-sweep – are you confusing this with CPython? OP's code will absolutely leak memory (`$foo` has a refcount of two, and will never drop to zero unless the circle is broken by reassignment or reference weakening). However, the scalar `100` will be garbage-collected.

Comment: @amon It seems the mark-and-sweep is only run on exit. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972021/garbage-collection-in-perl).

Comment: @Phylogenesis, actually a circular reference *is* a memory leak, because the clean-up doesn't happen until the program exits.

Comment: @dan1111 To be fair, my point about the memory leak was a direct answer to the question about whether the scalar value leaks.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

The value 100 was overwritten. When you assign a value into a variable, it replaces the previous value.

```
my $foo = 100;
$foo = "a string here";
```

The value 100 has gone. The same thing happens in your code above. The only difference is what kind of value was put in there.